# Are there small registers in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

I recently started playing with ARM assembly and notice I only seem to be about to move 32 bit values into registers but what if i wanted to only move 8 or 16 bits into the registers like in x86 assembly. 
i.e.

```
arm
eor r0, r0
mov r0, #128

x86
xor eax, eax
mov al, 0x80
```

r0 now contains 0x80 but it is a 32 bit register so it will contain 0x00000080

if this was x86 i could use al (8 bit register) to manipulate the last byte instead of eax (32 bit register).

tl;dr Are there small registers in ARM assembly?

Comment: Do you have any documentation on ARM assembly? To change only the lower x bits, you need to clear them with AND, then set with OR.

Comment: RISC architectures almost always work on the whole register. There's no way to operate on a small part of the register

Comment: related: [Direct Arithmetic Operations on Small-sized Numbers in RISC Architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47666871/995714)

Comment: That x86 code saves 1 byte of code-size vs. 5-byte `mov eax, 0x80`, but it's not worth it.  Compilers will use `mov eax, 0x80` because it's more efficient to run one single-uop instruction instead of 2, even if it costs an extra byte of code size.  A better example would be something like `shl al, 4` to implement `(uint8_t) (x<<4)`, not shifting bits past that 8-bit boundary into the higher parts of EAX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. ARM registers are 32-bit<sup>1</sup>.

However, assuming you're on a recent enough architecture version (ARMv6T2 or later) you can use the `BFI` and `UBFX` instructions to insert/extract an arbitrary slice of a register from/to the bottom of another without affecting the other bits. Doing the same with an immediate operand is a little trickier since `MOV` zero-extends immediates<sup>2</sup> (i.e. the `eor r0,r0` in your example is entirely redundant) - you'd either have to use `AND` and `ORR` as mentioned, or use an intermediate register for `MOV` followed by `BFI`.

---

[1] Well, "fixed-size" is more appropriate once you consider AArch64 state - there you have 32-bit and 64-bit views of the same registers, but any writes to a 32-bit view implicitly zero the upper 32 bits, so the same principle still applies (i.e. it doesn't allow you to pretend you have twice as many half-sized registers like an 8086).

[2] The exception to this is `MOVT`, which loads an immediate into the upper 16 bits of a register without touching the lower half (to allow loading a full 32-bit immediate with a `MOVW`/`MOVT` pair)

Answer (score 3):

```
arm
eor r0, r0
mov r0, #128
```

why not just do this instead:

```
mov r0,#128
```

No reason for the eor...

No you dont have the same 8 bit history with arm, so the registers started off from the beginning as 32 bit.  but you still have a number of instructions that help you do sub-32 bit operations on the registers.

Comment: I figured the xor was pointless since the entire 32 bits are modified but I left it in because symmetry is pretty...

Comment: understood, you could have just used a 32 bit immediate in x86 as well as an alternate example since you were trying to modify the whole 32/64 bit register not just 8 bits in your example.